# HTML5 circle animate so it looks like it is floating

Tags: jquery, html, animation, html5-canvas, geometry

So i am sort of a novice at html 5 and i am trying to make a circle look like it is just floating there so it is not perfectly still is this possible and if it is can you help?
and how do you make the canvas 100% width and 100% height so it fills the whole screen?
and do you need a canvas to draw it else how would you do it?

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 70;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
```

Comment: What does this mean? Do you want to randomly move around? IF so, why not just change centerX and centerY by a random number ecah frame? (i.e. add on a random # between say, -0.5 and 0.5 so that it moves slightly?

Comment: no so if you left it it would like hover in the middle it moves just slightly but all around the screen just in the middle, and you cant move it with your mouse

Comment: That sounds like you are describing the behaviour I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at my code on my question: [mouse-over-html-5-canvas-image-in-animation-to-play-pause-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680148/mouse-over-html-5-canvas-image-in-animation-to-play-pause-it). The code in my question does the same thing that you want. Maybe it could be of some help to you.